# Two factor authentication on ssh server with Google's Authentication

Tags: server, ssh, authentication

I've followed several different guides on how to configure two factor authentication on my ssh server using the google's libpam-google-authenticator.  I've been able to get it to work but when I try and log in from my desktop or any other device over the ssh I have to give it my ssh-key, user password, and then the authenticator token.  But in my sshd_config file I have:

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive  
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes  
PasswordAuthentication no   
UsePAM yes
```

And in my `/etc/pam.d/sshd` I added

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

So I think it should not ask for password as well. How can I fix it?

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: I dont want it asking for the password only my ssh key and the authentication token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out the line `@include common-auth` from your `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. It will ask only for the second factor (if configured!).

Answer (score 0):

Basically @Jakuje is right.

The common-auth contains a line with pam_unix.so. I would create a new file /etc/pam.d/google_auth and include this in your /etc/pam.d/sshd instead of common-auth. This way you are more modular.

The google-auth would basically look like this:

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]     pam_google_authenticator.so
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one    
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

This way you can include the `google-auth`in whichever service you like to.